# Getting data from one column based on the value of other column

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am having trouble coming up with an algorithm for the following problem:
I have two data frames, df1 and df2 (the following are just an example):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1, 7, 10, 50, 73, 80 ], 'Col2': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [0, 4, 10, 80], 'Col3': [7,6,8,9]})
```

As you can see, they both have the Col1, but the values aren't always coincident, but they are in ascending order. I want to create a function that will create a new column on df1, let's call it Col4. The values on this column have to come from df2 following these rules:

1) If df1 and df2 have the same value in Col1, the value in Col4 should be the corresponding value in Col3.

2)If they do not share the same value in Col1, Col4 should be the average between values in Col3 that correspond to the values immediately before and after it.

For example:

As df2 does not have a value in Col1 for 1, the first entry in Col4 should be the average between 7 and 6 (1 is between 0 and 4).

I don't know if I made myself very clear, but the final result for Col4 should be:

(7+6)/2, (6+8)/2, 8, (8+9)/2, (8+9)/2, 9

It would be nice to have a function because I will have to make this operation on many different data frames.

I know it is a weird problem, but thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want proper interpolation?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understood what you mean by proper interpolation.

Comment: For instance, 1 is 25 percent of the way between 0 and 4. So the value for 1 may be 7 (the value corresponding to 0) with 0.75 weight + 6 (the value corresponding to 4) with 0.25 weight, for a value of 6.75.

Comment: Oh, I see! I haven't thought of that, that is a great idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want with `pandas.merge_asof`

You merge `df1` with `df2` on `Col1` in both directions, `forward` and `backward`. Then you simply average the results. I've concatenated the two merges into one `df` column-wise and renamed the columns so they don't wind up with the same names.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='Col1').rename(columns={'Col3': 'Col4_1'}), 
                pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='Col1', direction='forward')[['Col3']].rename(columns={'Col3': 'Col4_2'})], axis=1)

print(df)
#   Col1  Col2  Col4_1  Col4_2
#0     1     1       7       6
#1     7     2       6       8
#2    10     3       8       8
#3    50     4       8       9
#4    73     5       8       9
#5    80     6       9       9

# Calculate the average you want, drop helper columns.
df['Col4'] = (df.Col4_1 + df.Col4_2)/2
df.drop(columns=['Col4_1', 'Col4_2'], inplace=True)

print(df)
#   Col1  Col2  Col4
#0     1     1   6.5
#1     7     2   7.0
#2    10     3   8.0
#3    50     4   8.5
#4    73     5   8.5
#5    80     6   9.0
```